# How do I install Microsoft.Net.Http via Nuget to Xamarin.Forms PCL project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget, nuget-package, xamarin-studio

Since System.Net.HttpClient is not accessible in Portable Class Libraries, I am attempting to install Microsoft.Net.Http package from Nuget to a HelloWorld Xamarin.Forms PCL project in Xamarin Studio but it always fails with this error:

```
Could not install package 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.0.20710.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

According to the [Nuget page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.2.22) for the project it does have support for PCLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEBKAC error here.

On the Add Packages screen in Xamarin Studio, I had Libs selected and not All Sources. Switching to All Sources allowed me to find the proper nuget package.